# getting error while executing npm install in ubuntu

Tags: npm

I am getting error while executing npm install command in Ubuntu. nodejs, grunt and bower components all are installed. Below is the error snippet

`

```
npm WARN package.json tag-builder-server@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json tag-builder-server@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql.git) fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql.git) github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-64-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/Nyder/Nad/Nad_poc/Nadid
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/Nyder/Nad/Nad_poc/Nadid/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

`

Please help fixing this

Answer (score 0):

As per:

```
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql.git) fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/felixge/node-mysql.git) github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
```

request to Github.com is getting timed out, which means that either your network connection is not working or Github is not accessible from your location, please update your question with the output of `ping github.com`

Answer (score 0):

the same problem 
that is my gihub ping :

```
--- github.com ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 24036ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 95.669/95.958/96.662/0.489 ms
```